# Adobe Illustrator save to PDF "a drawing error occurred"

Tags: pdf, adobe-illustrator, illustrator-cs6

I have a illustrator file with several layers and shapes that I need to save to a PDF in order for others to view and print. However, when I save to PDF, and open in Acrobat, I get the message "a drawing error occurred"

- Is there something in the image itself that is incompatible with PDF? (text, outlines, gradients, resolution, ect?)
- Is there something in my illustrator settings that is incompatible with PDF?
- Is it possible my image is too complicated to export to PDF?

What can I do to find out what might be causing the error, or is there some way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that is a problem with my Acrobat reader, not the file itself. I don't know how to fix the problem with acrobat, but at least I know its irrelevant to the illustrator file